How to fix "The Alias Device to use as local I/Os is not supported by the selected Target System" in a TwinSafe project?
In a TwinCat 3 TwinSafe project I want to use an EL1918 both as safety target system and as safety input device. I have configured the El1918 as safety target system. But I cannot find it when using the "Import Alias Devices from I/O-configuration" dialog. Also, when adding an EL1918 alias device manually and setting its linking mode to local, I get the following error message:

The Alias Device to use as local I/Os is not supported by the selected Target System. Please check the target system settings/firmware and/or the settings of the Alias Device.

How can I get this configuration to work?
I have used such a configuration sucessfully in other systems and I am not aware of any difference between my acutal system and others that worked fine. The TwinSafe firmware update wizard does not find any updates for this device. The Diag-History of the box does not yield any error. An I have no idea, which setting of either the target system or alias device could have anything to do with the problem at hand.

This error might arise when the Alias Device does not match the revision of the EL1918. As of now, there are two different Alias Devices avaliable for different revisions of the EL1918:

"EL1918, 8 digital inputs" for EL1918 with revision 16 and lower
"EL1918, 8 digital inputs (FW 2)" for EL1918 with revision 17 and higher

The correct Alias Device needs to be used in order to successfully configure the system. The revision of your EL1918 can be found in the EL1918 I/O device 's "EtherCAT" tab. for Example, the EL1918 rev 17 would have the revision code EL1918-0000-0017.
If you are using older versions of the TE9000 TwinSAFE Editor, you might need to update it to use newer revisions of the EL1918 as the "EL1918, 8 digital inputs (FW 2)" Alias Device is only avaliable from TE9000 TwinSAFE Editor version 1.3.5 onward.
For the Update to take effect, it might be necessary to delet all templates under C:\ProgramData\TwinCAT Safety\AliasDeviceTemplates\6a974e40-4af7-4d63-9a6b-32894bc485f2\Safety\EtherCAT\Beckhoff Automation GmbH & Co. KG after updating.
